# Swift OneSignal Duplicate PlayerId's and PushToken's

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

I am using Onesignal with Firebase, yet my problem is that the same PlayerID and PushToken is generated for all users. I have a picture below showing the printouts of the UserID and PushTokens. I had deleted my app from my device and reinstalled it. The 1st print out is from the AppDelegate where I get the "Would you like to allow notifications?", then the 2nd print out is where my "Customer" is creating a profile. The 3rd print out is after the "customer" creates a profile, yet the 3rd userID and push token are different, yet do not save as so. What am I doing wrong? The 2nd printout is what I am getting for all users.

**app delegate**

```
let notificationReceivedBlock: OSHandleNotificationReceivedBlock = { notification in

        print("Received Notification: \(notification!.payload.notificationID)")
    }

    //OneSignal.add(self as! OSSubscriptionObserver)

    let notificationOpenedBlock: OSHandleNotificationActionBlock = { result in
        // This block gets called when the user reacts to a notification received
        let payload: OSNotificationPayload = result!.notification.payload

        var fullMessage = payload.body
        print("Message = \(fullMessage)")

        if payload.additionalData != nil {
            if payload.title != nil {
                let messageTitle = payload.title
                print("Message Title = \(messageTitle!)")
            }

            let additionalData = payload.additionalData
            if additionalData?["actionSelected"] != nil {
                fullMessage = fullMessage! + "\nPressed ButtonID: \(additionalData!["actionSelected"])"
            }
        }
    }

    let onesignalInitSettings = [kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: false,
                                 kOSSettingsKeyInAppLaunchURL: true]

    OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions,
                                    appId: "\(appID)",
                                    handleNotificationReceived: notificationReceivedBlock,
                                    handleNotificationAction: notificationOpenedBlock,
                                    settings: onesignalInitSettings)

    OneSignal.inFocusDisplayType = OSNotificationDisplayType.notification

    let status: OSPermissionSubscriptionState = OneSignal.getPermissionSubscriptionState()
    OneSignal.setSubscription(true)
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    print("##############################")
    let userID = status.subscriptionStatus.userId
    print("userID = \(userID)")
    let pushToken = status.subscriptionStatus.pushToken
    print("pushToken = \(pushToken)")

    if pushToken != nil {
        if let playerID = userID {

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: your problem is different Player Id and Push Token are getting printed at multiple instances of the same session of your app? Or same Played ID and Push token is getting for different users from different devices? Sorry I couldn't understand the problem. But I hope this is something I can help, because I've integrated one signal recently.

Comment: I am getting the same UserId and PushToken for all users

Comment: What I am showing is me trying to find out why this is happening, even though some how in the 3rd print a different userid and push token is being printed

Comment: Sorry my code was wrong, I was just printing the Firebase UID, not the Onesignal Id, so it's still wrong on all ends. The same id is being given.